Is it worth it to use a NoSQL database only for high availability and fast reading, while already using Postgres?
We have several Postgres databases on one AWS RDS cluster (for budget reasons apparently), sharing the same resources, and my team wants to use a NoSQL database alongside it, and store data there from a specific table.
It's a table with 7 columns, and there's an endpoint that does a query similar to this:
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE
    field1='something'
    AND field2='something'
    AND field3='something'
    AND field4 NOT IN ('value1', 'value2');

This table has like 3 millions of rows, and on certain dates (like cyber day), the endpoint is called thousands of times. The table is only written with a cron job, I think it's once a day (it has data from several tables, it was created just to have easier access to that data). Since everything is in the same RDS cluster, if one database collapses, all the operation does. This already happened last cyber day, there were timeouts in a lot of endpoints, and the queries to this table were a part of the issue.
What my team wants the most is to separate this data, to alleviate load from the RDS cluster, and to avoid having a single point of failure. And we also need fast reading and high availability, so my team is thinking about using a NoSQL database, because they're supposed to be better at fast reading and availability. Is this true for this specific case? Would that be any better than a properly set up postgres database? (I mean using indexes, efficient queries, etc).
I'm not sure if doing this would improve our situation or not, either way there's a lot to improve, and I'll try to push the conversation towards refactoring code and using indexes, so that the endpoint only does a few queries, hopefully just one, and as efficiently as possible. And also I'll ask for better monitoring, so we can better identify the bottlenecks. But either way I need to justify my arguments for or against using a NoSQL database.
As far as having this table sharing resources with the rest of the data, which is one of the main concerns, there are some other solutions, like using read-only replicas in RDS. What do you think? Do you have any other suggestions for this?

Make tests and measure it. There's no other answer to this kind of questions.

Databases can have drastically different performance. When people praise NoSQL for having fast reads, that's often related to using the database more like a key-value store, an apples-to-oranges comparison. It is fairly common to combine an RDBMS with a KV cache, e.g. Valkey (Redis), which can help reduce repeated queries, but this can introduce data consistency headaches. It's also fairly common to regularly export data into a search index like OpenSearch (Elasticsearch), or into an analytics-oriented DB. But integrating another DB sounds much more complex/expensive than adding good indices…

Do you have control over the processes calling the endpoints?

What was the performance of the database on cyber day?  Also, were they are queries taking a long time?   One may need autoscaling so that instance can grow in size with memory and connections on busier days.  Caching could be option, since updates only occur once a day, but I am not sure if the same queries are coming in or if they are all variable.  With 7 columns and 3 million rows you might end up many results on the cache if each one is different (variable).

"the endpoint is called thousands of times" over the course of the whole day?  That's not much volume.

You'll have to measure it to be sure. But I suspect there's a lot of optimizations you can do with Postgres to get the same kind of performance improvement.

Read-only replica databases are a very neat feature with Postgres.  The best thing about them is that there's no code or schema you need to write and keep version controlled.  If you're doing some kind of ETL process to move your data into a NoSQL schema, remember that you'll have to maintain that ETL process forever.  So, using a read-only replica gives you a database you can run long slow queries on without blocking your regular users from using your production system.

The reason to use NoSQL databases isn't performance, its scalability. So if you just replace 1 RDBMS with 1 NoSQL db, well it's still the same CPU doing the same work at the end of the day.
To see a performance improvement you need to spread the DB across multiple servers and balance the load accordingly. NoSQL solutions can be better at this than relational DBs because you don't have the joins causing consistency problems.
If however, you just duplicated your single read only table on to two, or more, postgres DBs, well you have achieved the same thing with no technology changes.
The real question is how easy do the two solutions make the clustering/sharding/load balancing setup. If you use DynamoDB autoscaling you might find it solves everything out of the box with minimal config, compared to working out how to replicate and balance multiple postgres dbs.
I imagine what you are looking for is peace of mind on those sale days. Which an autoscaling solution will give you. You don't want to be manually spinning up new DB instances and fiddling with connection strings while all the alarms are going off because your volumes hit the limit of the 3 DBs you thought would be enough.

"it's still the same CPU doing the same work at the end of the day" that doesn't mean anything at all. It's not about CPU, it is about algorithms and data structures, and optimizations. There might be a performance benefit from giving up on consistency, even with single database instance. Which btw many nosql solutions claim to be true. Which I strongly doubt, well at least Mongo has been shown multiple times to be similar to Postgres.

unlikely with a single table

Of course it is possible. For example Postgres follows MVCC for all tables. So it copies entire rows on every update. In a situation where you have lots of columns and lots of small updates this will be significantly slower than other databases. While at the same time (parallel) reads can be significantly faster. Which again: has nothing to do with CPU.

The table has 7 cols. But I think you are missing the point, sure one DB might be better than another at some defined task, and you could test them all to see which is best. But NoSQL doesn't have any in built advantage over other approaches on the same hardware. It's optimised case is distribution

Choosing a technology to solve a problem before the problem is well understood is a good way for wasting time and energy.
First of all, the volumes that you indicate are not very high.  I have seen a lot of RDBMS-based solutions that handle much higher volumes without any performance issue. Moreover, it seems not either to be a very complex query:  no join,  only value selections. A selection on a combination of several fields is something that an RDBMS usually does at least as well as a NoSQL.  The advantage of NoSQL lies elsewhere.
The first step to the solution is to be able to measure the performance under heavy load, and identify the root-cause:

is it really the query on the table?  Then, was the query analysed and optimised, e.g. what about adding some indexes, including composite indexes?
or is it because the database is also under heavy load due to other activities?  In this case,  could it be considered to use a different isolation level,  to reduce locking that may create unexpected bottlenecks?

In the worst case, before considering NoSQL, why not simply create or replicate this table in another instance, or another cluster? This seems relevant if your table is created periodically via a cronjob, is read-only, and moreover not involved in transactional stuff.  It would have the advantage of keeping the technology stack homogeneous, while distributing the workload.
I also read in other answer that NoSQL would be more scalable.  Maybe, maybe not.  NoSQL is not better, it's different.  It's not a performance guarantee: There are things that NoSQL can do better (store flexible data structures in document dbs,  have lighter retrieval if the problem can be expressed in terms of key-values,  navigate more efficiently across complex evolving structures, if the problem can be expressed as a graph, ...).But each of this advantage come with some inconvenience as well.
Postgres and RDBMSes in general are also scalable, with sharding, partitioning, and replication. Again, this is not a universal solution and solves only some kind of problems.
My whole point is not that Postgres can do everything and you should keep it,  but that you should make your choice based on evidence and a good understanding of the root cause.
